Suspend mode crashes Ubuntu 24.04
I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5 with AMD Ryzen™ 5 5500U with Radeon™ Graphics × 12, with Ubuntu 24.04 installed.
IF I close the lid the laptop goes into suspend mode. If I do this more than one time maybe 3, sometimes on the first suspension, the OS freezes or crashes. Sometimes a black screen appears and Ubuntu bar icons start to vanish.
I do not know what can be done. I am just a basic normal user of the operating system, so I can not do skilled things on my laptop. My hope is for updates and fixes.
just now, an error appear after suspend the system, that was a white page saying that the system crashes and couldnt recover,and have to restart the session i click on ok, then login again. Maybe its something to to do with the session but i dont know if is that
i have set to wake uo into the session without password lock , but if i remenber correclty with lock on after suspension also crashes but not sure

After the system comes up again, the terminal command sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex will show the system logs leading up to the crash /shutdown. You can look at other shutdowns by varying the -b -1 option. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do sudo journalctl  --list-boots. For more journalctl help, see my AskUbuntu profile (click on my username).

the command on the terminal says invalid option -- 1

And on windows 11 suspention mode works fne in the same laptop, hope for better updates

Sorry, typo. sudo journalctl   -b -1 -ex
